# MAXIFS with date column as a condition

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I need to calculate a largest value in a column, based on the date in another column. The condition, is for it to be in August of 2021.

I tried to use `MAXIFS` but I'm not sure how to specify the condition?

```
MAXIFS(D2:D39, B2:B39, MONTH=8, YEAR=2021)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=MAXIFS(D2:D39, B2:B39, ">=" & DATE(2021,8,1), B2:B39, "<" & DATE(2021,9,1))
```

Maximum value from Column D, where Column B is Greater Than or Equal To (i.e. "on or after") the start of August, and Column B is Less Than (i.e. "before") the start of September.

Comment: That's good. Thanks. Just remove that extra comma from the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data looks like, but you could try query (Google Sheets):

```
=query({B:D},"select Col1 where year(Col3) = 2021 and month(Col3)+1 = 8 order by Col1 desc limit 1 label Col1 ''",1)
```

[image]